# Am I supposed to keep asking the same question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, user-interface

At the bottom of the questions I ask, the page shows text similar to the following one.

[image: screenshot]

Am I supposed to ask again the same question?

The code clearly noticed I asked the question; in fact, it doesn't show any form field to enter a question, and the "Add Your Answer" button is replaced by the "Answer your Question" button. In the same way, the "or ask your own question" part should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this has come up before, and although I think it's completely trivial, it's easier to make the change than keep reading people's complaints about this trivial issue.

So

> or ask  your own question.

or

> or ask another question.

Comment: IMO, remembering to a user who already asked a question that he can ask another question is not necessary, as he has already shown to know how to ask questions. If the text is changed when the user is who asked the question, would not it be easier to remove that part at all?

Comment: so you want to go even deeper down the trivial rabbit hole, then? :p

Comment: Sigh! I should not write, when my attention deficit disorder kicks in. I hope the sentence I wrote is still understandable.

Comment: "Ask another question" is good, though, as I could be searching for a question and, following a link (which could be a link given on Google or any other search engine), go to a question I asked. It would create a disparity, if the link were present in questions asked by others but not mine.